# Which property to change for item to adjust width and wrap other items on flexbox row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am building a dashboard with multiple charts. By default, each chart will take 1/3 of the row width (3 charts on the row). I would like to give the user an option to choose chart width (1/3, ½ or 100% width) for each chart.

What would be or is there a clean way to do that with flexbox? If so, which css/flexbox property(s) I would need to change on element so the chart width changes, and the next chart(s) on the row would wrap accordingly?

The closest I have gotten to the desired result is having `flex` on parent div and `flex: 1 0 33%;` for the children (charts). And I would need to provide a user a way to change the`33%` value. Not sure if this is the recommended/reliable way?!

Comment: Can you share what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following can work for you.

use [flex-flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow) so specify that elements should stack in a row and wrap if needed.

You can simply toggle the `half` and `full` classes as needed.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.item {
  width: 32%;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.item.half {
  width: 50%;
}

.item.full {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="item half">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="item full">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great! I added `flex: 1 0 32%; min-width: 600px` to the `item` so `items` don't collapse on narrow screens but wrap around and take up the available width.